# Why the Recordset from VBA just return one record?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 3 tables, "persons", "per_resi" and "residence"
This three tables form a many to many relation.

Table "person" fields:  id, name etc....

Table "residence" fields: id, Street etc.....

Table "per_resi" fields: person_id and residence_id  (together principal index)

Well, the problem is when I design a query in the graphic Access tool it Works as it should be.

[image]

But if I do in VBA it only return 1 record.

```
Dim svivienda As String
Dim rvivienda As Recordset

svivienda = "SELECT tbl_persona.Id, tbl_vivienda.Calle, tbl_vivienda.Numero " _
          & "FROM tbl_vivienda INNER JOIN (tbl_persona INNER JOIN tbl_perso_viv ON tbl_persona.Id = tbl_perso_viv.Id_persona) " _
          & "ON tbl_vivienda.Id = tbl_perso_viv.Id_vivienda WHERE tbl_persona.Id = " & 168 & ";"

Set rvivienda = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(svivienda, dbOpenDynaset)
```

I have tried LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN but always the same just one record on the recordset.

Any ideas?

MS access 2013

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you copy this from the Query Wizard?  How are you assessing it contains 1 record?

Answer (score 1):

Thank guys,

This was a very novel question.

Here is the answer.

The RecordCount property does not report the amount of records you have.

> The value of the RecordCount property equals the number of records
>   that have actually been accessed. For example, when you first create a
>   dynaset or snapshot, you have accessed (or visited) only one record.
>   If you check the RecordCount property immediately after creating the
>   dynaset or snapshot (assuming it has at least one record), the value
>   is 1. To visit all the records, use the MoveLast method immediately
>   after opening the Recordset, and then use MoveFirst to return to the
>   first record. This is not done automatically because it may be slow,
>   especially for large result sets.
>
> [Count the number of records in a DAO Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/count-the-number-of-records-in-a-dao-recordset)

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you look at ADO and different arguments for cursor etc, you can use the recordcount property

Answer (score 0):

Add following statement :

```
rvivienda.MoveNext
```

will return the next record of the recordset
or :

```
rvivienda.MoveLast
```

will return the last record of the recordset

You will see the result.

The [goosie2018's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520778/10026099) is CORRECT. I just show you the simple way to understand.

**SUMMARY**

So, I think the recordset you get from the database will not show the result look like an Array or a List, but a cursor. And the default cursor points to the first row, so if you use :

```
rvivienda.RecordCount
```

you should receive the number of records you actually got.

Sorry for my English ! And thanks for reading.